# Geometry Trasformation in Spatialite 4.1.1

Tags: spatialite

I am trying to transfrom below grometry (geo referenced to australia)

> POLYGON((-33.917172 151.110971,-33.916443 151.112495,-33.917637
>   151.113276,-33.917783 151.111512,-33.917253 151.111577,-33.917172 151.110971))

from SRID 4326 to 3112 using below query

```
SELECT AsText(Transform(PolygonFromText('POLYGON((-33.917172 151.110971,-33.916443 151.112495,-33.917637 151.113276,-33.917783 151.111512,-33.917253 151.111577,-33.917172 151.110971))',4326),3112)) as result
```

in spatialite GUI 1.7.1 with spatialite 4.1.1 with all GEOS,PROJ extensions enabled but the resulting geometry is

> POLYGON((Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf, Inf Inf))

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy, you just have to invert LON/LAT values:

```
SELECT AsText(Transform(PolygonFromText('POLYGON((151.110971 -33.917172, 151.112495 -33.916443, 151.113276 -33.917637, 151.111512 -33.917783, 151.111577 -33.917253, 151.110971 -33.917172))',4326),3112)) as result
```

result:

```
POLYGON((1569305.481332 -3926985.759663, 1569455.307825 -3926925.091727, 1569508.606645 -3927065.382207, 1569345.639225 -3927059.314561, 1569359.502478 -3927002.182676, 1569305.481332 -3926985.759663))
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text

```
POLYGON(x y) = POLYGON(lon lat)
```